# How to get percentage of how much do two body overlap?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I am new in LibGdx and I want to know how can I get the percentage of how much two bodies overlap. For now all I know is that I need to use Contact Listener but than what? I am using LibGdx in java not c++. Is there a way of getting the size of surface of the bodies and maybe comparing them somehow? I will appreciate any kind of help. :)

For example.. Let´s say we have 2 bodies (SQUARES) named b1 and b2. One of them is set as sensor so that they can go through each other. And what I want to do is that console prints out the percentage of how much they overlap when their x coordinate is same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For two polygons, you could use a polygon clipping algorithm to find the overlapping region. There are examples in many languages here: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sutherland-Hodgman_polygon_clipping

For two circles it's much easier, you should be able to find how to do that with a quick google search, eg. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html

For a circle and a polygon, I'm not aware of any easy or convenient method.

Comment: I forgot to mention that two bodies are squares, so I should use polygon clipping algorithm? There is a lot of code that I don`t understand, but I think I can figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: I´m sorry for bothering but I just can´t get it done. Any possible way that you can clarify it for me a bit?